# notation for clusters of 2D data points

Tags: notation, data-analysis, clustering, scientific-notation

Is there any convention about the notation to use for clusters of $2-$D data points?

I have a set of clusters of $2-$D data point. I can denote each cluster with $c_i$, where $i = 1, 2, ..., n$, and $n$ is the total number of clusters.

All the clusters lie at different distances from a certain point $p$, and I know all the distances from each cluster center to that point $p$, i.e. $d_1, d_2, d_3, etc..$.

Also, I know an approximate area for each cluster, that I can denote with $A_1, A_2, ...$

I would like to write down the *area of the closest cluster* to the point $p$, but I am not sure about the way to do it, according to potential conventions.

Could you please tell me if my attempt might be aligned to possible conventions on the notiation?

\begin{equation}
A_{min(d)}
\end{equation}

or

\begin{equation}
\left.A_i\right|_{min(d)}
\end{equation}